# How to count the 0`s of a string inside a nested list with python and print its indexes

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, counting

I want to return the count of zeros in a nested list such as the following one

```
 lista = [['0000', '', ''], ['', '', '000', ''], ['000', '0', ''], ['', '', '00', '', '']]
```

for that list it should return:

```
                               [[[4, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]],
                                [[0, 0], [0, 1], [3, 2], [0, 3]],
                                [[3, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2],
                                [[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 2], [0, 3]]
```

That's it the count of zeros for each string plus the index...
What is the the most pythonic way to do that?

Comment: Is this always a 2-level array?

Comment: Yes, @SreekantShenoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list contains only empty strings and strings of `0`s then this should work.

```
result = [
    [(len(element), index) for index, element in enumerate(sub_lst)]
    for sub_lst in lista
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple looping and count will do.

```py
nums = [['0000', '', ''], ['', '', '000', ''], ['000', '0', ''], ['', '', '00', '', '']]

result = []
for num in nums:
    counts = [[el.count('0'), i] for i, el in enumerate(num)]
    result.append(counts)

print(result)
```